# Unused Parameter in Implementation of Delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a validation pattern with a delegate like this

```
public bool IsPropertyValid<TValue>(
    TValue value,
    Func<TValue, bool, string?, (bool IsValid, IEnumerable<string> ErrorMessages)> 
        validationDelegate,
    bool mandatory,
    string? errorSuffix = null)
{
    // Validate using the delegate
    var (isValid, errorMessages) = 
        validationDelegate?.Invoke(value, mandatory, errorSuffix) 
            ?? (true, Enumerable.Empty<string>());

    //do stuff
}
```

I have a bunch of validation methods setup to match the delegate requirements

```
public static (bool IsValid, IEnumerable<string> ErrorMessages) 
    ValidateTextOnly(string value, bool mandatory, string? msgSuffix = null)
{
    return ValidationMethods.IsTextOnly(value, mandatory)
        ? (true, Enumerable.Empty<string>())
        : (false, new[] { ErrorMessage("must be letters only",
            msgSuffix, mandatory) });
}

public static (bool IsValid, IEnumerable<string> ErrorMessages) 
    ValidatePostalCode(string value, bool mandatory, string? msgSuffix = null)
{
    return ValidationMethods.IsPostalCode(value, mandatory)
        ? (true, Enumerable.Empty<string>())
        : (false, new[] { ErrorMessage("must be a valid postal code",
            msgSuffix, mandatory) });
}
```

This produces the final error message, possibly irrelevant to the question

```
private static string ErrorMessage(string? message, string? msgSuffix,
    bool mandatory)
{
    message = string.Join(mandatory.Value ? " and " : " or ", 
        new [] { mandatory.Value ? IsRequired : NotRequired, message }
            .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)));
    return string.Join(" ", new[] { message, msgSuffix }
        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)));
}
```

This bit below is the bit that bugs me.  This validation method doesn't use the `mandatory` bool at all.  It's checking for empty, so `mandatory` doesn't make sense.  I realize I'm nit-picking, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to write this than just leave the dummy parameter in the function header.

```
public static (bool IsValid, IEnumerable<string> ErrorMessages) 
    ValidateEmpty(string value, bool mandatory, string? msgSuffix = null)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)
        ? (true, Enumerable.Empty<string>())
        : (false, new[] { ErrorMessage(null, msgSuffix, false) });
}
```

I've considered, rather than using a mandatory flag, to double up each validation method like `ValidateText()` and `ValidateTextMandatory()` but that seems worse.  I've considered making the `mandatory` bool in the delegate nullable, but `null` is hardly valid for all the other validation functions.  Perhaps `ValidateEmpty()` isn't appropriate for the pattern but I'm not sure the alternative.

Looking at this I may want to consider turning the tuple result into it's own class... but that's a separate issue.

Comment: As far as I see, `mandatory` flag is used in delegates `ValidateTextOnly` and 'ValidatePostlCode`, its value is being passed to `ErrorMessage` and influence error message (null - message as is, false - adds 'or not required', true - adds 'and required'.

`ValidateEmpty` delegate does not use `mandatory` flag (pass null to ErrorMessage to avoid message alteration) because error message 'Value is empty and is required' would be same information presentred twice.